# Excel changes the numer of Invoice for date

Tags: excel

My company uses some web app to store all invoices, every month I must send the list of all invoices to my Boss. It's quite easy as I can generate CSV file containing a list of invoices. There is just one problem, excel changes some of the numbers of invoices for a date. Let say I have I Invoice number 01/03/2021 I generate the file, open it in excel and there you go excel convert it to 01.03.2021. I open it in any simple text editor and the number of the invoice is fine, then I open it in excel and again the same it's changed to date. [image]

As you can see in the picture up above there is the invoice number "1/03/2021", but when I open it in the excel:

[image]

Is there any way to prevent this? Any option in Excel to change to fix this problem. Of course, I tried to do a custom format, it changed some of the rows but on other popped errors. Any Idea of how to prevent this?

Comment: You could try putting a single quote (') in front of the date. eg '1/03/2021. That should stop Excel trying to convert it.

Comment: I would make sure invoice numbers don’t look like dates - ever.

Comment: We are talking about the invoices sent by our contractors, I don't ask them to change the format of their invoice numbers. Any other solution?